# Compute cumulative specular value

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an array of object like this:

```
const data = [
  { value: 0.35, name: 'a' },
  { value: 0.12, name: 'b' },
  { value: 0.05, name: 'c' },
  { value: 0.25, name: 'd' },
  { value: 0.23, name: 'e' },
]
```

the sum is exactly 1.0.

This is the result I want to get:

```
const data = [
  { value: 0.35, name: 'a', cumulativeValue: 0.35 },
  { value: 0.12, name: 'b', cumulativeValue: 0.47 },
  { value: 0.05, name: 'c', cumulativeValue: 0.52 },
  { value: 0.25, name: 'd', cumulativeValue: 0.48 },
  { value: 0.23, name: 'e', cumulativeValue: 0.23 },
]
```

The logic is to add value until the sum exceeds 50, as soon as this value is exceeded then it calculates the cumulative value starting from the end of the array.

Here is my code, it works but is there a more elegant way to do that?

```js
const data = [
  { value: 0.35, name: 'a' },
  { value: 0.12, name: 'b' },
  { value: 0.05, name: 'c' },
  { value: 0.25, name: 'd' },
  { value: 0.23, name: 'e' },
]

function computeCumulative(data) {
    const newData = data.reduce((prevWithCumPercentages, datum, i) => {
      const cumulativeParcentage = i === 0 ? 0 : prevWithCumPercentages[i - 1].cumulativePercentageL
      const newDatum = {
        ...datum,
        cumulativePercentageL: datum.value + cumulativeParcentage,
      }
      prevWithCumPercentages.push(newDatum)
      return prevWithCumPercentages
    }, []) 

    const dataReverse = [...data].reverse().reduce((prevWithCumPercentages, datum, i) => {
      const cumulativeParcentage = i === 0 ? 0 : prevWithCumPercentages[i - 1].cumulativePercentageR
      const newDatum = {
        ...datum,
        cumulativePercentageR: datum.value + cumulativeParcentage,
      }
      prevWithCumPercentages.push(newDatum)
      return prevWithCumPercentages
    }, []) 

    const data2 = dataReverse.map((datum) => {
      const { cumulativePercentageL, cumulativePercentageR } = datum
      const omitted = omit(datum, ['cumulativePercentageL', 'cumulativePercentageR'])
      const cumulativePercentage =
        cumulativePercentageL <= 0.5 ? cumulativePercentageL : cumulativePercentageR
      return { ...omitted, cumulativePercentage }
    })
    
    return data2
  }

console.log(computeCumulative(data))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure is elegant enough. I would not use functional programming for this,  where simple loop is enough.  This assignment is very tricky because of border condition ( when condition fires, it shall apply to the next value).  This would mean  either some if clause  or simply iterating in reverse direction.   Thanks to @Yoshi for pointing it out

Simple java code:

```
double[] values = {0.35, 0.12,0.05,0.25,0.23 };

double cumulative = 0;
for(int i = values.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    cumulative += values[i];
    double c = cumulative < 0.5 ?  cumulative  :1 - cumulative + values[i];
    System.out.println("c[" + i + "]=" + c );
}
```

Produces:

```
c[4]=0.23
c[3]=0.48
c[2]=0.52
c[1]=0.47
c[0]=0.35
```

---

A javascript version would be:

```js
const data = [
    { value: 0.35, name: 'a' },
    { value: 0.12, name: 'b' },
    { value: 0.05, name: 'c' },
    { value: 0.25, name: 'd' },
    { value: 0.23, name: 'e' },
];

for(let i = data.length - 1, cumulated = 0; i >= 0; i--) {
    cumulated += data[i].value;

    data[i].cumulated = cumulated < 0.5 ? cumulated : 1 - cumulated + data[i].value;
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: There's a minor error on the `c` entry. But you can fix this, if you traverse backwards: `for(let i = data.length - 1, cumulated = 0; i >= 0; i--) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: Is `int` valid JavaScript?

Comment: @customcommander it is pseuqdocode ( I am mostly developing java and c -   some bad habits and statuc typing )

Comment: @Yoshi why traversing backwards? atual value is already added for last half

Comment: Would you mind, if I changed your code example to a javascript version? With the question being about javascript?

Comment: Not a problem.   Being java developer it is easier for me to whip  Junit test as JS snippet

Answer (score 0):

You could take a closure over the sum and a flag for being in the first or second half of adding/subtracting of the value.

For the last object take the original value to omit floating point arithmetic errors.

```js
const
    data = [{ value: 0.35, name: 'a' }, { value: 0.12, name: 'b' }, { value: 0.05, name: 'c' }, { value: 0.25, name: 'd' }, { value: 0.23, name: 'e' }],
    result = data.map(((cumulativeValue, first) => (o, i, { length }) => {
        if (first) cumulativeValue += o.value;
        const temp = { ...o, cumulativeValue };
        if (!first) cumulativeValue -= o.value;
        if (cumulativeValue > 0.5) {
            first = false;
            cumulativeValue = 1 - cumulativeValue;
        }
        return i + 1 === length
            ? { ...o, cumulativeValue: o.value }
            : temp;
    })(0, true))

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```